# Find the maximum likelihood of k

Tags: statistics, density-function, estimation, maximum-likelihood

A population has a density function given by
f(x)=(k+1)x^k 0<x<1
0 otherwise
For n observations,x1,x2,x3...xn made from this population, find the maximum likelihood of k.

Here's my attempt:
I have got k=-1-n/(product of log xi fron i=1 to i=n).

Im not sure if it's correct.
Can somebody help?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1653643/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3643141/321264

Comment: Thank you sm @StubbornAtom